# How to suppress "Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test" warning message?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, machine-learning-model, hyperparameter-tuning, hyperparameter

I am working on hyper-tuning random forest classifier with following parameters in random search CV

```
In [100]: # defining model

Model = RandomForestClassifier(random state=1)

# Parameter grid to pass in RandomSearchCV

param grid =
{ "n_estimators": [200,250,300], "min_samples_leaf": np.arange(1, 4), "max_features": [np.arange(0.3, 0.6, 0.1),'sqrt'],"max_samples": np.arange(0.4, 0.7, 0.1)}

#Calling RandomizedSearchcV

randomized_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=Model, param     distributions=param grid, n_iter=10, n_jobs = -1, scoring=metrics.make_scorer(metrics.recall_score))

#Fitting parameters in RandomizedSearchcv

randomized cv.fit(X train, y train)
print ("Best parameters are {} with CV score={}:" .format (randomized_cv.best params_,randomized_cv.best_score_))


 File "/Users/thiyaga/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site- packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in
 call
 return [func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/thiyaga/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-   packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in <listcomp>
 return [func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/thiyaga/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site- packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 222, in
 call
 return self. function(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/thiyaga/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site- packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 169, in parall
 el build trees
 tree.fit(X, y, sample weight=curr sample weight, check input=False)
 File "/Users/thiyaga/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/tree/classes.py",line 903, in fit
 super@).fitl
 File "/Users/thiyaga/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py",line 273, in fit
if self.max features > 0.0:
ValueError: The truth value of an arrav with more than one  element is ambiguous. Use a.an() or a.all()
warnings.warn ("Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test"
```

output is

Best parameters are

```
 {'n estimators': 250,
 'min samples leaf': 1,
 'max samples': 0.6,
 'max features':'sqrt'}
```

with CV score=0.6996248466921577; along with this warning message. To avoid warning message imported

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
from sklearn.exceptions import FitFailedWarning
```

still warning message appears.

Answer (score 1):

In the param_grid
`"max_features": [np.arange(0.3, 0.6, 0.1),'sqrt'],` this code essentially means
`"max_features":[[0.3 0.4 0.5],'sqrt']`, which is a nested array, this is ambiguous for RandomSearchCV.

Instead of that, you can expand and write as `"max_features": [0.3 0.4 0.5,'sqrt']`. This helps RandomSearchCV to look into the array and returns the best max_feature value.

Hope this solves :)